# extrude mesh along z axis using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, extrude

As I have started the creation of my mesh using geometry nodes I cannot use the simple "extrude mesh" function in edit mode it seems.

I would also like to keep the extrude "interactive" by adding it to my geo node setup.

When using the extrude geometry node I only can extrude along the normals it seems, where I would just like to extrude it along the z axis.

Anyone has a few tips for me, would be very grateful.

I am using Blender 3.3 alpha

Cheers, Methexisdesign

Comment: Could you please explain this with a picture. Also a screenshot of your node tree can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just plug in vector like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Crantisz, this worked for me!

Comment: @Methexisdesign If this answer solved your question, please be so kind and mark the answer as "Accepted Answer". Thank you for helping to keep this platform clear and tidy. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)